# Dompdf, carregar link stylesheet

Tags: html, css, html5, dompdf

Estou tentando carregar o `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.aaaa.dev/assets/css/imprimir-mod-1.css">` mas não é carregado quando o PDF é gerado.

Se abro a página sem gerar o PDF carrega o CSS corretamente.

O que preciso fazer?

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$MM_authorizedUsers = 'a';
include __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../../permissao.php';

$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM aaaa WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' && a = '".$_SESSION['a']."'");
$row = $rs->fetch_assoc();

ob_start();
?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Codigo <?= $row['codigo'] ?></title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.aaaa.dev/assets/css/imprimir-mod-1.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <table class="w100p space">
        <tr>
            <th>Logo</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Codigo:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table class="w100p space left">
        <tr>
            <th>CLIENTE</th>
            <th>LOCAÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table class="w100p space left borda" >
        <tr>
            <th>DESCRIÇÃO</th>
            <th>DIAS</th>
            <th>VALOR</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
                <table class="totals borda">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="w200p">TOTAL DA FATURA</td>
                        <td class="w200p">R$ 0,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DESCONTO</td>
                        <td>R$ 0,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DEPÓSITO</td>
                        <td>R$ 0,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>TOTAL A PAGAR</td>
                        <td>R$ 0,00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    </body>
    </html>

<?php
//exit;
$html = ob_get_clean();
require __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$arquivo = "Codigo ".$row['codigo'].".pdf";

$dompdf->stream($arquivo, array("Attachment" => false));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, para referenciar um arquivo CSS no *DOMPDF*, você deve mencionar o caminho completo do arquivo, tente **`href="https://seusite.com/./../../assets/css/imprimir-mod-1.css`** ou o caminho desejado.

Comment: Douglas, tinha feito o teste apenas via html e abriu, mas agora quando fui gerar o PDF ainda não carregou o CSS. Coloquei o link direto como informado.

Comment: Nesse seu arquivo CSS, só possui definições de estilo? ou em algum momento está se referenciando há uma imagem? Eu utilizo `DOMPDF` também, e para carregar arquivos CSS, só precisei fazer o que está na resposta, mas se for imagens remotas, você precisa fazer mais coisas...

Comment: Apenas CSS, veja https://jsfiddle.net/5cs3koja/

Comment: Tente referenciar embaixo, assim:  `$dompdf->load_html('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.aaaa.dev/assets/css/imprimir-mod-1.css">

  '. $html .'

    ');`

Comment: Tambem não funciona :( desisto...rsrs, perdi 1/2 dia, tentando achar uma solução.

Comment: Tem algo a ver, estou testando em localhost

Comment: Desiste não cara, eu também quebrei a cabeça um pouco para personalizar os meus relatórios em PDF utilizando DOMPDF, qualquer coisa, tenta baixar outras versões, procura exemplos prontos, etc...

Comment: Qual sua versão?

Comment: Cara se eu não me engano, utilizei do Celke hahaha... [link](https://celke.com.br/artigo/como-gerar-pdf-com-php-e-mysqli-utilizando-o-dompdf)